# Mysql deadlock : what does 'try restarting transaction' mean and what exactly happens to the locked transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions, deadlock

I have a situation where 2 transactions create a mysql deadlock.

The following error is fired : `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

If I'm correct, this error means that mysql deadlock timeout is expired, and mysql try to do something to removes this deadlock.

What isn't clear for me is what means `try restarting transaction` ? How a transaction can be "restarted" ?

What happens to the 2 locked transactions ? Are they both canceled (roll-backed) ? Or is it just one of them that is canceled so the lock can be released.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no deadlock timeout (though there are lock timeouts). If a deadlock is detected, no amount of time will resolve it, so MySQL reacts immediately.

MySQL will roll back one or more transactions until the deadlock is resolved.

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html):

> InnoDB tries to pick small transactions to roll back, where the size
>   of a transaction is determined by the number of rows inserted,
>   updated, or deleted.

It is up to your application that is making the SQL call to retry the transaction.

MySQL has some recommendations in its documentation [How to Cope with Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html).

If you wish to try to avoid the deadlock and are having trouble understanding the cause of the deadlock, I recommend starting another question, and posting the complete affected queries and schema, and ideally the deadlock report from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.

Comment: Ok so MySQL won't retry to restart on of the transaction by itself, I miss-understood the message : it's just an advice. Thanks for the timeout information, I made a confusion whith the following error : `ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout`. This topic helped : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808986/when-does-innodb-time-out-instead-of-reporting-deadlock